# setting an integer valued variable in CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to have a user specified value for openmp threads through CMAKE and so I set a variable as follows:

```
set(NUM_THREADS "3" CACHE STRING "Number of OpenMP threads to use")
```

I can pass this to my code as:

```
-DNUM_OPENMP_THREADS:STRING=${NUM_THREADS}
```

Now when I do the openmp pragma in my C++ code as:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_OPENMP_THREADS) schedule(static,1)
```

This comes back with the error:

```
error: ‘num_threads’ expression must be integral
```

This makes sense, of course but for hours now I am unable to figure out how to make this variable got from CMAKE so that it will be parsed as an integer.

Comment: Is the `NUM_OPENMP_THREADS` variable passed as a preprocessor definition via `target_compile_definitions()` or similar?

Comment: When calling cmake, I do: `-DNUM_OPENMP_THREADS:STRING="2"`. The whole cmake is slightly complicated with super build and all that but essentially, I am using `set` and this seems to just let me use string types.

Comment: You need to also `add_compile_definitions` to pass it to the compiler